# EnableAuthorizationServer 2.4.0 migration

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

We have recently updated our Spring Boot application (OAuth server). Since Spring Security OAuth 2.4.0 RELEASE EnableAuthorizationServer seems to be deprecated. 
We read migration guide but we haven't found any section about authorization server.

Do you have any details about the migration? Is migration recommended, or can we keep the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring's Roadmap, they don't have a plan for authorization server support anymore.

https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/14/spring-security-oauth-2-0-roadmap-update

No Authorization Server Support
In October 2012, RFC 6749, the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework, was published. Subsequently in May 2014, Spring Security OAuth released its 2.0.0 version with support for Authorization Server, Resource Server, and Client. This made a great deal of sense in the absence of OAuth 2.0 libraries and products.

Answer (score 1):

Since @han-lee posted, a new Spring project has been created to fill this gap: https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server

See the news post [here](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/15/announcing-the-spring-authorization-server).